# How/should I display data that has different units in a chart?

Tags: gui-design, charts

I need to display some data for users to look at at track their progress, and at first I thought of using a line chart, which at a glance seems okay.

[image]

But the problem is there are 2 different units displayed, kgs and cm. (Technically there are 4, kgs/lbs, and cm/inches but the user chooses which metric they want on a settings page).

The issue I think the chart has, is the value could be mis-read. You see the value is 50, but because I can't label the V axis, and there are multiple units, you have to look further to understand what the value applies to.

Is this as much of a problem as I think it is, or am I thinking too hard about this?

If this could be an issue, does anybody have any suggestions on how else I could display this data?

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomharto/L2zhp4mc/) with some test data, and a chart if anybody wants to have a play with it.

Update: 
This is what I ended up with.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're right to be mildly concerned about mixing the units, and even if you could label the Y axis, it wouldn't make the problem go away.

If you want to remain consistent in your units, breaking things out into tabs is a reasonable option, though it does detract from the 'at-a-glance' value of the data display.

Creating tabs gives you a couple more opportunities to use labels (i.e. in the tab label) to reconfirm the metrics - "This tab is for kg. This tab is for cm" - so in the measurements tab, you don't have to repeat it for every measurement i.e. "Waist, Bicep" not Waist(cm), Bicep(cm)

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDvA8p.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I like the tab idea a lot, thanks :). I think this is what I'll end up going with, but I'm just gonna wait a little while, see if anybody else comes up with anything.

Answer (score 3):

Combining two types of data in one chart makes it difficult to read and understand at a glance. If you really have to keep them in one chart, consider using a visibly different display type - e.g. a **bar chart** to display kilograms and **line chart** to plot centimeters.

A nice example could be seen here: [Highcharts dual axes demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes), also pictured below:

[image: Highchart two axes demo]

Note that there are two axes on both sides of the chart. This allows you to have two independent ranges of values for both data types. Still, it's not a perfect solution - if your design allows for some more space, try splitting it into two charts, which would greatly improve readability.

Comment: I like this idea, but I don't feel it works as well with the data as the tab idea does. Definitely a good idea though :).

Answer (score 0):

We dealt with this question at my job recently and we used multiple charts in a dashboard design at first. This made it very clear what data set you were viewing, since each chart had a prominent title.

In a later iteration, we switched to a solution similar to tabs: a dropdown menu to select a metric. The switch made it easier for users on mobile devices to view the data. They had much less scrolling to do when they viewed one chart at a time.

You can see our project at http://www.zingchart.com/demos/fantasy-football/